# Based on regular expression

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, theory

Explain the following 2 regular expressions. Where would they be used? What potential problems do you foresee in using them?

1. `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([_.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?@[a-zA-Z0-9]+([_-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*([.]{1})[a-zA-Z0-9]+([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$`
2. `^[^<>&~\s^%A-Za-z\\][^A-Za-z%^\\<>]{1,25}$`

Comment: Is that homework?

Comment: @Diego: Looks like it...

Comment: "Explain what happens when you have this question on a mid-term and can't ask StackOverflow for help"

Comment: I guess "sadistic" goes well for some teachers

Answer (score 2):

The first one validates an email address. One of the problems with it is that, while being generally accurate, it's not perfect and will let some emails go through.

For example, a lot of people use the the plus sign '+' to add a 'comment' to their email address. This regular expression won't pass those.

Answer (score 1):

The first one seems to describe a weird subset of an email address. The second one seems to describe a sequence of between 2 and 26 numbers and other characters not present in the square brackets...